# React native Typescript path alias unable to resolve module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, babel-plugin-module-resolver

so basically, I created my React Native with Typescript using the commandline in RN homepage:
`npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript`

After that, I ran the project and it was built successfully.
However, when I added the path alias to import my file, it threw an error: `Unable to resolve module #folder/file from  ... could not be found within the project or in these directories: node_modules`

I've **already followed** some tutorials and bug resolves on Google but **I've met no luck.**

Here is my `.babelrc` file (I **tried to change the file** from babel.config.js to .babelrc as some resolver said but it still didn't work)

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["./src"],
        "extensions": [
          ".js",
          ".jsx",
          ".ts",
          ".tsx",
          ".android.js",
          ".android.tsx",
          ".ios.js",
          ".ios.tsx"
        ],
        "alias": {
          "#src/*": [
            "./src/*"
          ],
          "#configs/*": [
            "./src/config/*"
          ],
          "#actions/*": [
            "./src/redux/actions/*"
          ],
          "#reducers/*": [
            "./src/redux/reducers/*"
          ],
          "#store/*": [
            "./src/redux/store/*"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "esnext", 
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "ES2017",
      "DOM",
      "ES2015",
      "ES2015.Promise"
    ], 
    "allowJs": true, 
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "noEmit": true, 
    "incremental": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".", 
    "paths": {
      "#src/*": [
        "src/*"
      ],
      "#configs/*": [
        "src/config/*"
      ],
      "#actions/*": [
        "src/redux/actions/*"
      ],
      "#reducers/*": [
        "src/redux/reducers/*"
      ],
      "#store/*": [
        "src/redux/store/*"
      ]
    }, 
    "types": ["jest"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, 
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": false, 
    "resolveJsonModule": true 
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ]
}
```

My folders and files structure

```
├───assets
├───components
├───config
│       constants.ts
│
└───redux
    ├───actions
    │       index.ts
    │       stateActions.ts
    │
    ├───reducers
    │       index.ts
    │       stateReducer.ts
    │
    └───store
            index.ts
```

Really looking forward to receive you guys answers. Thank you so much

P/s: if you dont mind, please take a look at my repository:
https://github.com/NotJackieTruong/rn_test_typescript

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Thor0o0 the solution that worked for me was to remove `/*` from all of the aliases and directories. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 20):

For [expo v49+](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/typescript/#absolute-imports):

1. module-resolver is not required, you can remove it from babel-config
2. Add to **app.json**:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "experiments": {
      "tsconfigPaths": true
    }
  }
}
```

3. Define `paths` as usual in `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To make this work just need add `package.json` file to each directory you want to access with one property `name` in it. For example:

```
├───assets
└───components
    └───package.json
```

`package.json` content:

```
{
  "name": "components"
}
```

And then you can import like this:

```
import SomeComponent from 'components/SomeComponent';
```

There is also a [good article](https://belighted.com/blog/react-and-react-native-directories-management) describing how this works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I have to add package.json to each directory every single time I add new components? It doesnt sound like a good method... But anyway, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: I'd also love to know why my config doesnt work and be looking forward to more practicle solutions

Comment: interesting, but I think it will be a bit redundant if we can do it without `package.json` on every directory.

Comment: From my experience I usually add `package.json` to several directories under source folder. For example `assets`, `components`, `utils`. These folders are very stable during whole project lifecycle.

Comment: I define a package.json in the root directories (under src directory) and it's working very well without any extra packages or configs. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

tsconfig.json

```
 "baseUrl": ".", 
 "paths": {
      
      // this is for src directory
      "@*": ["src/*"],
      "@configs/*": ["src/config/*"
      ],
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
        plugins: [
            [
                "module-resolver",
                {
                    alias: {
                        "@config": "./src/config",
                         ....
                        
                    }
                }
            ]
        ]
    };
};


        }
```

Answer (score 3):

add this to your `tsconfig.json`

```
"include": ["./src/**/*"]
```

then restart your TypeScript Server

`Cmd+Shift P` then choose `TypeScript: Restart TS server`

Edit: this is the tsconfig.json I'm using if that helps

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "./App.tsx"],
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base"
}
```

Comment: thank you, but it still not working... I've already cleared cache, restarted the metro server, typescript but still met no luck

Comment: the weird thing is that when I import the file, vscode still recommends the right directory and when I click to it, it brings me to the right component.

Comment: @jackieTruong123 by right directory, does it use the path you specified in the config? btw, I put my `tsconfig.json` there for reference. I don't know why yours doesn't work, but let me know if you find the solution.

Comment: I tried to delete the paths or point to the wrong ones in the config file and it show import errors, so I assume that it uses my path specified in the typescript config

Comment: I added my repository to the questions. If you dont mind, please take a look and help me, please. Thank you.

Comment: @jackieTruong123 hey, I just tried to open that but it gave me 404

Comment: hi, so sorry for that. That project goes private now so you cant go inside. instead, you can check my new repository for that. Those 2 repos are having the same problem :|

Answer (score 2):

In tsconfig.json

```json
{
...
   "compilerOptions":{
        ...
       "baseUrl":"."
       "paths":{
            "@folder": "src/folder" <--assuming app logic is in src/ 
        }
   }
}
```

In babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
...
  plugins: [
    ["module-resolver",{
      "alias":{
        "@folder": "./src/folder",
      }
    }]
  ],
};
```

Uninstall the app from emulator/device

Restart the metro server `yarn start --reset-cache`

Build the app `yarn run android/ios`

Answer (score 1):

For those who still stuck with the issue
with all solutions you have just make sure the following:-

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

or

```
yarn add --dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

babel.config.js or .babelrc

**make sure this is development not production in babel** <<<<<<<<<<<<< VIP

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
  env: {
    development: { // <<< make sure this is development not production
      plugins: [
        'react-native-paper/babel',
        [
          'module-resolver',
          {
            root: ['./src'],
            extensions: [
              '.js',
              '.jsx',
              '.ts',
              '.tsx',
              '.android.js',
              '.android.tsx',
              '.ios.js',
              '.ios.tsx',
            ],
            alias: {
              '@hooks': ['./src/hooks'],
              '@familyway': ['./src'],
              '@assets': ['./src/Assets'],
              '@components': ['./src/Components'],
              '@constants': ['./src/Constants'],
              '@helpers': ['./src/helpers'],
              '@onboarding': ['./src/onBoarding'],
              '@redux': ['./src/redux'],
              '@screens': ['./src/Screens'],
              '@lib': ['./src/lib'],
              '@containers': ['./src/containers'],
            },
          },
        ],
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

ok now with the tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext",
      "esnext.asynciterable",
      "esnext.intl",
      "esnext.symbol",
      "esnext.array"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,
    // "noImplicitThis": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "incremental": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@hooks/*": ["hooks/*"],
      "@components/*": ["Components/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["Assets/*"],
      "@screens/*": ["Screens/*"],
      "@constants/*": ["Constants/*"],
      "@helpers/*": ["helpers/*"],
      "@onboarding/*": ["OnBoarding/*"],
      "@redux/*": ["redux/*"],
      "@containers/*": ["containers/*"],
      "@lib/*": ["lib/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "additional.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "./App.tsx",
    "./src/**/*",
    "src/**/*",
    "src/**/*.*"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After long efforts and trials, I was able to make the path alias work with "@" as follows;

**Note:** My all codes in src directory.

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src'],
        alias: {
          '@': './src'
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was not using `expo`. I initiated my project using `npx react-native init <App name>--template react-native-template-typescript`. I ran into issues once I added path aliases to my `.babelrc` and `tsconfig.js`. I tries several instructions but nothing worked. My successful attempt was.

1. Deleted `node_modules` and `yarn.lock`
2. Converted `babel.config.js` into `.babelrc`. (Cannot gaurantee if this had to do with the success).
3. Uninstalled the app from the emulator
4. Ran `yarn` to install all the dependencies.
5. Ran `yarn start --reset-cache` to install and run the app while removing the metro-cache.